# Android Subsampling Zoom Image View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've just tested the Dave Morrissey's Subsampling Zoom Image View:

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

How can I load images from a specific folder in the Android Sd card (and not from the assets folder)?

Here are the classes involved:

public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private static final String[] IMAGES = { "ness.jpg", "squirrel.jpg" }; // Open an external folder int the sd card and load my .jpg images into an array dynamically to show on ViewPager.

private ViewPager page;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.view_pager);
    getActionBar().setTitle("View pager gallery");
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    page = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    page.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (page.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        page.setCurrentItem(page.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    finish();
    return true;
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ViewPagerFragment(IMAGES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.length;
    }
}
```

}

public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String BUNDLE_ASSET = "asset"; // It seems it uses this as the folder name and I would like to change that to another.

private String asset;

public ViewPagerFragment() {
}

public ViewPagerFragment(String asset) {
    this.asset = asset;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.view_pager_page, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (asset == null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(BUNDLE_ASSET)) {
            asset = savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_ASSET);
        }
    }
    if (asset != null) {
        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)rootView.findViewById(id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageAsset(asset);
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    View rootView = getView();
    if (rootView != null) {
        outState.putString(BUNDLE_ASSET, asset);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setImageFile` method and supply the path of the file you want to display.

```
imageView.setImageFile("/sdcard/DCIM/DSCM00123.JPG");
```

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks for the quick response. The library is awesome.

Comment: But that way I need to know the name of the image. And if I want to load the all content of the folder... something like:

File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/sdcard/DCIM/*.jpg"